# Why 1s complement is -2

Tags: c, complement

```
int main()
{
       int a=1,b;
       b=~1;
       printf(""%d",b);
       return 0;
}
```

pls explain by showing bitwise operation it will be helpful to understand...

thanks in advance.......

Comment: (compare with an *unsigned* operation / print)

Comment: And why are there three double quotes?

Answer (score 8):

It's exactly what you might imagine.  `1` is `00000001` in binary (number of digits depend on size of `int` on your platform).  `~1` performs a bitwise-inversion, i.e. `111111110`.  In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) (the most common system of binary arithmetic), this is equal to `-2`.

Answer (score 3):

This identity should help you remember the behaviour of `~`:

```
~x == -x - 1
```

Applying it to 1:

```
~1 == -1 - 1
   == -2
```

In bits:

```
 1 == ...0000000001
~1 == ...1111111110  # flip the bits

 0 == ...0000000000
-1 == ...1111111111  # two's complement representation for negative numbers
-2 == ...1111111110
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening:

```
 1:  00000001
~1:  11111110
```

If you think about a signed integer,
      0:  00000000   -1
     -1:  11111111
     -2:  11111110

Basically, start from zero and subtract two and see what you get.